# Orbits / phase space for ODE.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm quite confuse with several definition. Let consider the ODE $$\dot x=f(x).$$

As I understand, orbits are the sets $$\mathcal O(x_0)=\{x(t)\mid t\in I, x(0)=x_0\}.$$

Now, I'm a bit confuse with the Phases space. I always thought that it was $$\bigcup_{x\in \mathbb R}\mathcal O(x),$$
(we suppose that $\mathcal O(x)$ is well defined for all $x$), but in some example it works, but in some it doesn't. Suppose that I have the ODE $$\begin{cases}\dot x=y\\ \dot y=-k^2x \end{cases}.$$
So it's a pendulum. And indeed, here, the phase space is $\bigcup_{x\in\mathbb R}\mathcal O(x)$ and near to equilibrium points, these are circle.

---

But for example, if I consider the ODE $y'(x)=\sin(y(x))$, in my course they say that the phase space is  $$\bigcup_{x_0\in\mathbb R}\{(x(t),\dot x(t))\mid t\in I, x(0)=x_0\}\tag{D}.$$ But these are not orbits... So according to my definition, the phase space should be $\bigcup_{x_0\in\mathbb R}\mid \{x(t)\mid t\in I,\exists s: x(s)=x_0\}$, but according to $(D)$ the phase space of the pendulum should be $$\bigcup_{}\{(x(t),\dot x(t),y(t),\dot y(t))\mid...\}$$

so I'm quite confuse. What do you think ?

Comment: Are you sure it is not the physical pendulum $\ddot x+\sin(x)=0$? This would then just be the same orbit definition, only expanded in some cautious fashion to make the associated first order system explicit.

Comment: @LutzL: Yes I'm sure. Which definition you think is wrong ?

Comment: $(x,\dot x)$ is one parametrization of the state space of a second order equation. A first order example equation does not make any sense here. (A consistent naming of dependent and independent variables could also help.)

Comment: You mean that $y'=\sin(y)$ doesn't make sense ? But for example, suppose we can't solve $y'=f(y)$, the set $\{(y,y')\mid y\in \mathbb R\}=\{(y,\sin(y))\mid y\in\mathbb R\}$ give us a lot of information about $y$, no ? So what would be called this space $\{(y',\sin(y)\mid y\in\mathbb R\}$ ?

Comment: The set of the pairs $(y,\sin(y))$ is usually called the graph of the sine function. The orbits in the scalar case are the intervals of constant sign of $f$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confused because your notation is overloaded. Consider the linearized pendulum, given by the equation 
$$
\ddot{y}(t) = -ky(t). 
$$
Here $y$ is the *physical position* of the pendulum in some system of units.

Notice that this equation is NOT in the form $\dot{x} = f(x)$, but can be written in this form by defining two *state variables* $x_1(t) := x(t)$ and $x_2(t) := \dot{x}(t)$. We define the *state vector* $x$ to be the vector of all the state variables, that is, $x(t) := [x_1(t) \ x_2(t)]^T$. In terms of the state variables, the system has the form
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{x}_1(t)\\ \dot{x}_2(t)\\
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
x_2(t)\\ -kx_1(t)\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which IS in the form $\dot{x} = f(x)$, where $x$, again, is the state vector. Hence, the orbits are of the form

$$
O(x_0) := \{x(t) \ | \ t\in I, x(0) = x_0\} = \{[x_1(t) \ x_2(t)]^T \ | \ t\in I, [x_1(0) \ x_2(0)]^T = [x_{1,0} \ x_{2,0}]^T\}
$$

where I have defined initial conditions in the obvious way.

The phase space is defined to be

$$
\bigcup_{x\in \mathbb{R}^2}O(x) = \bigcup_{[x_{1,0} \ x_{2,0}]^T\in \mathbb{R}^2}\{[x_1(t) \ x_2(t)]^T \ | \ t\in I, [x_1(0) \ x_2(0)]^T = [x_{1,0} \ x_{2,0}]^T\}
$$

but in your notation $x_1 = x$ and $x_2 = y$. Note that $\dot{x} = y$ so it doesn't make sense to include both of them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I agree for the Orbit. But what about the phases space ? Is it $\{(x_1(t),x_2(t),\dot x_1(t),\dot x_2(t))\mid ....\}$ or it's just $O(x_0)$ as you wrote ? Because on wikipedia they sometime include momentum and sometime not.

Comment: @user657324 I updated my answer to include the phase space. Your first definition is correct except that the initial condition is a vector in general, so the union is usually over a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Ok, good point ! So, if $y'=\sin(y)$, the phase space is $\bigcup_{x\in\mathbb R}\{y(t)\mid t\in I, y(0)=x\}$, right ? But what would be $\bigcup_{x\in\mathbb R}\{(y,\sin(y))\mid y(0)=x\}$, because seeing the graph $\{(y,\sin(y))\mid y(0)=x\}$ we can really understand better how $t\mapsto y(t)$...

Comment: 1) yes. 2) I am not aware of any such construction. In first and second order systems, stability can be studied geometrically by plotting either $f(x)$ or a vector field. To my knowledge, no such method exists in higher dimensions